# Populate Azure Mobile Apps backend data

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Hi and thanks in advance.
I'm experimenting with a Xamarin.Forms app to handle various events organized by my company (one a month), and I'm taking a cue from the great app made by Xamarin ​​for Evolve16.
But I don't understand how I can populate the database created in Azure backend with code first. I know there is a Seed method to eventually do this the first time but next? Every month I need to add new data (for example new sessions) quickly, and I do not want to provide this functionality within the app because the app should only provide contents to users. All domain obejects inherit from EntityData so I don't know if I can use LINQPad or SSMS to insert data directly because there are fields populated automatically (Version, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt...). Can I use rest api of backend table controllers? But where is the "try out" possibility that there was in Azure Mobile Service??

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to answer this.  Basically, you want to alter the underlying tables in the SQL database

1) aka "the simple version" - download the SQL Server Management Studio and do raw inserts into the table
2) aka "the separate website" - write an ASP.NET web app that uses Entity Framework to do the inserts for you.  Make sure you include the Azure Mobile Apps Server SDK and make your models inherit from EntityData.
3) aka "the combined website" - download the Node project that underlies the service and adjust it to add your own website that can do the inserts for you.

The "try out" option is now implemented with swagger.  Just go to https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/swagger

Comment: Thanks Adrian. But the project already has a .Net backend https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/ This backend exhibits controllers and so I asked if I can use these in a fast way. I'll try swagger